# Django - how to filter OneToMany relationship on same instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

Lets assume I have the same models file

class modelA(models.Model):
b_model = models.ForeignKey(modelB, related_name='modelA')
...

class modelB(models.Model):

Where modelB can have multiple instances of modelA related to him,
If I perform the following code:
outcome = B.objects.filter(modelA__in=[1,2,3])

Should B object will return if *any* of his modelA in [1,2,3] or *all* of his modelA in [1,2,3]?
I want the second option, how can I achieve it?

Another question regarding this code:
outcome = B.objects.filter(modelA__gt=1, modelA__lte=3)
I want to check the condition on the **same instance** of modelA, how can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

I looked everywhere online and couldn't find a solution, hope you can help me

Comment: Please edit and format your code for helping us to read your question

Answer (score 0):

First question: `outcome = B.objects.filter(modelA__in=[1,2,3])` should return b objects where modelA is 1 or 2 or 3. The lookup `in` is like an IN SQL operation in a where clause.
Django provides documentation with all of this information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in

For the second question: `B.objects.filter(modelA__gt=1, modelA__lte=3)` should not work I think. modelA represents an object, so comparing it to an integer will crash I suppose. You can do what you want to by selecting a field in modelA: `B.objects.filter(modelA__FIELD__gt=1, modelA__FIELD__lte=3)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think you didn't get my intention...
I want to know what happens when modelA is a group of object and not one.. so I think your answer regarding the two parts is not accurate..
Regarding the second part, even if I access a specific field which is an integer, what happens if there are more than one object who is modelA?

Comment: I understood your question. my answer remains unchanged. Why do you not test your code with `python manage.py shell`? Probably simpler than asking about hypothetic usage. If you access a specific field, the filtering will be applied for finding modelB with a model which respect all filters